# Given density $f(x,y,z)$, how can I find its mass with 3-D integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Given density $f(x,y,z) = y^2$ , the others are planes.

I need to compute $\iiint_V y^2dxdydz$.

I'm left to find the integration range of $x,y,z$ I believe it would be:
$z = 0 , z = 1 - x$ , and then I need to find $x,y$ which is the orthogonal projection on plane $xy$, thus $z=0$ , so $ x = 1, x =y^2$, and $y = -1, 1$?

If anyone can help me to get this right it'd be highly appreciated! thx!

Comment: Draw the shape. It helps.

Comment: @Argon I want to be able to solve this without drawing.

Comment: I've never found that using purely algebraic manipulations made anything easier. Indeed, I find it usually harder.

Comment: is this everything which was given to you? If not, please post the whole question. I mean, if you consider your set, it pretty much looks like a set of two points $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,0);(1,1,0)$